# $Im(A+B) \subset ImA + ImB$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, where $m,n
>  \geq 2$.
>
> A. $Im(A+B) \subset ImA + ImB$
>
> B. $\ker(A+B) \subset \ker A + \ker B$

I figured out a counterexample for B: take $A = I$ and $B = -I$. Could you help me to prove A?

My attempt: $Im (A + B) = \{(A+B)x\} = \{(Ax + Bx\} = Im A + Im B$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last inequality is incorrect. The correct statement is slightly weaker
$$\{Ax+Bx\}\subset \{Ax+By\} = \operatorname{Im} A + \operatorname{Im} B.$$

Comment: That explains why there is no equality sign in the statement of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: It should be $\{Ax+Bx\}\subset \{Ax\}+\{Bx\}$.

Comment: @mathcraze It's correct as written. The variables $x$ and $y$ are implicitly quantified over all elements of the vector space (separately).

Comment: It is better written in $\{Ax\}+\{Bx\}$, which is more clear.

Comment: @mathcraze Actually, that seems less clear to me. In any case, the asker had no trouble understanding what I meant.